# Why does Guy consider changing sex?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-x-files

In the third episode of the tenth season of *The X-Files* Mulder and Guy Mann have the following conversation:

> MULDER: That's because she used to be... uh, she once... She's
>   transgender.
>
> GUY MANN: (Disbelief) What? You can't transform into a different sex!
>   That's nuts!
>
> MULDER: It's not nuts. It's actually a very common medical procedure.
>   You don't need the surgery, technically...
>
> GUY MANN: (Grabbing at straws) Maybe that's what I could do! It's a
>   cure!
>
> MULDER: No.
>
> GUY MANN: Well, I've got to stop transforming. I'll do the surgery.
>
> MULDER: Completely different.
>
> GUY MANN: (His mind made up) I don't care how much it costs, I'll do
>   it.
>
> MULDER: They cut off (nodding with his head towards GUY MANN's groin
>   area) your genitals.
>
> GUY MANN: (Thinking about it) Nah, I'll leave it. That's... that's a
>   step too far, isn't it?

I understand that this dialogue is there for the comedic effect and that Guy is grabbing at straws, but even so there should be some logic behind it. When he was trying to force Mulder to puncture his appending with a "lance" it was at least loosely based on the legend, while calling changing his sex "a cure" is lacking any sense to me.

Comment: *"based on the legend"* Maybe that's why, it was a *man* in the tale. So maybe he thinks changing *any* of the elements in the story will make it stop? He's new to humanity, remember... His logic is all skewed (by our standards).

Comment: @Walt The only explanation I could think of when writing this question was  very similar- that a _major change_ in him would stop the transformation, so I guess you're probably right. If you want you can write an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I should probably rewatch the ep first... Although it was nice, the rest of the revival was so dreadful, I kind of suppressed it all.

Comment: @Walt Agree. It was definitely the best episode of the revival, I also liked the one about the islamist terrorists. The rest was poor to mediocre.